# Connect internet through WIFI

Tags: ieee-802.11

In my office there is a internet connection and access by others computer through wifi router( D-link router). 
My home from office is about 2 km. It is possible to connect office wifi from my home with any wifi adapter to access internet.

Answer (score 1):

No. Some wireless technology has that range, but since the router is a D-link consumer grade device, it doesn't have that kind of reach.

The reason is even if you have a **very** strong receiver/transmitter for your adapter, which is not normal, the router would need a receiver/transmitter that's just as strong. It will need to receive your signal the same way you receive it's signal.

Note: this doesn't seem like it would be ok to do in the first place. Unless you own this company or have their explicit permission, I highly discourage doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's is not feasible, the typical office router signal is strong enough to get around 200m when there are *no obstacles* as walls, roof, etc. 
Just think the big amount of obstacles the signal will have to pass through between your home and the office.

Dense material as brick walls absorb part of the power of the signal and metal superficies reflex the signal, weakening it enough to being undetectable after a few meters.

Your office and yourself would need to install *high poles* on the roof to put there antennas on a *line of sight* without meaningful obstacles. Besides of that your device and the office device will need to be *high power* devices, not the tipical home/office devices.

Even with that, your signal will travel above other people's houses who use also wi-fi besides cordless phones and baby monitors that could interfere your signal causing some kind of *quality degradation*.

Comment: Actually, Wi-Fi is designed to give you the same 100 meter distance as a wired cable. Some people call it 200 meters only because it can go 100 meters in all directions, so you could have a client 100 meters to the North and another 100 meters to the South, and they would be 200 meters apart.

Comment: You're right. I used the typical measure between the most distanced clients and not the distance between AP and client.